# How to define org.hornetq.ra as resource adapter in WIldfly 8

Tags: java, jms, messaging, wildfly-8

can anyone help me about defining `org.hornetq.ra` module in Wildfly AS 8 as a `resource adapter` in `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:2.0">` section of `standalone-full-ha.xml`.

```
<resource-adapters>  
        <resource-adapter id="hornetq-ra.rar">  
            <module slot="main" id="org.hornetq.ra"/>  
            <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>  
            <config-property name="ServerUrl">jnp://localhost:1199</config-property>  
            <connection-definitions>  
                <connection-definition class-name="org.hornetq.ra.HornetQRAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/HornetQConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="HornetQConnectionFactory"/>  
            </connection-definitions>  
        </resource-adapter>  
    </resource-adapters>
```

I have used the above configuration but it is no getting registered as resource adapter and getting the below error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "resource-adapters"),
("resource-adapter" => "hornetq-ra.rar")
]) - failure description: "JBAS010473: Failed to load module for RA [org.hornetq.ra]"
```

Has anyone done this ? Please help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually tried that and I had lots if problems, so I decided to do the following instead.

```
<resource-adapters>  
    <resource-adapter id="my-hornetq-ra">
        <archive>hornetq-ra.rar</archive>
        <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>  
        <config-property name="ServerUrl">jnp://localhost:1199</config-property>  
        <connection-definitions>  
            <connection-definition class-name="org.hornetq.ra.HornetQRAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/HornetQConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="HornetQConnectionFactory"/>  
        </connection-definitions>  
    </resource-adapter>  
</resource-adapters>
```

NOTE: `hornetq-ra.rar` MUST be in the deployment directory and my-hornetq-ra is a reference that you will use in `jboss-ejb3.xml` when defining your MDB like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:jee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:mdb="urn:resource-adapter-binding">

<jee:assembly-descriptor>
    <mdb:resource-adapter-binding>
        <jee:ejb-name>*</jee:ejb-name>
        <mdb:resource-adapter-name>my-hornetq-ra</mdb:resource-adapter-name>
    </mdb:resource-adapter-binding>
</jee:assembly-descriptor>
```